# how to inspect docker's running container files

Tags: docker

I used to inspect docker's container file using `docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' container_id`, then the container's files are located in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/{container_full_id}`(I didn't change the default configuration, so it's the default location), the version of docker is 1.6.1 at that time.

But now, I'm running docker 1.10.3, I used the same command `docker inspect -f '{{.Id}}' container_id`, but I can't find the folder in the location that it used to be, nor in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diffs/{container_full_id}`.

Is it docker modify its folder structure, or is there anything wrong with my commands?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I found answer on docker's docs, It says:With Docker 1.10 and higher, container IDs no longer correspond to directory names under /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/<container-id>——https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/

Answer (score 0):

by writing "docker inspect containername" You should get full JSON info about container. There is some info about the paths like ResolvConfPath (so the location of the container files as well)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the command and found the ResolvConfPath, but it's a path that resolv.conf file located. There is no other useful information for the container's file location.

Comment: Hmm ... here is an info, that docker 1.10 changed name convention:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Also info about different storage drivers. Seems that You may find info there

Comment: Thanks barat. I found a document - https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/, it says that after 1.10, the folder structure has changed, container_full_id will not match the folder again. I'll look into the page you provide to find if there is other way to inspect the folders.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[docker-layer](https://gist.github.com/vincepare/fed1400108c70cda89eeaaf4f3cdc514) provide an easy way to find a container's filesystem root mount :

```
# docker-layer -m musing_wiles
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/c83338693ff190945b2374dea210974b7213bc0916163cc30e16f6ccf1e4b03f
```

Edit 2018-03-28 :
docker-layer has been replaced by [docker-backup](https://github.com/vincepare/docker-backup)